# C++ & .NET, garbage pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

My UI source is constructed with .NET

Also, I'm trying to connect the function of engine source(which is constructed with C++) to the UI.

One of the parameter in the function is Structure : stOutput

In my UI source I defined this Structure like below.
(All the data type of member variables is Integer and Double)

```
Public Structure stOutput
        Public lDate As Integer
        ...
        Public dMoney As Double
End Structure
```

Also In my engine source(dll), I defined this struct like below
(All the data type of member variables is Long and Double)

```
#pragma pack(8)
typedef struct  stOutput
{ 
        long lDate;
        ...
        Double dMoney;
}stOutput;
#pragma pop
```

I defined the function in the UI source(.NET) like this,

```
Public Declare Function Calc_Salary Lib "Salary" _
        (ByRef Output As stOutput) as Integer
```

I wrote it as 'ByRef' because the dll receive this Output as parameter, then it modifies values in the structure 'Output' then return the outcome that is calculated in the dll to UI.

And I defined the function in the engine source(dll) like this,

```
extern "C" long FuncExport __stdcall Calc_Salary(stOutput *Output);
```

The Main Problem is after the function conveys the value from dll to UI source, the value becomes garbage value.

when I debug it in the UI source, before calling the function 'Calc_Salary',
The variables have correct value ,for example.

```
lDate = 20210927
dMoney = 30000.00
```

When I debug it in the dll source, Input value is like below.

```
lDate = 20210927
dMoney = 30000.00
```

And, before returning the value from the function 'Calc_Salary',
Again the variables have correct value, for example.

```
lDate = 20210930
dMoney = 30200.05
```

Finally, when the function returns value to the UI source then the value becomes garbage like this

```
lDate = 20180230 (it seems like correct however, totally not reasonable value considering my logic)
dMoney = 5.7824553468304092E-254
```

I tried to match the name of variables in the struct.
And corrects all the typos one by one.
Also matches all the sequence of the variable and parameter.

But I totally don't know what is the reason.

**p.s. the parameter is like grid, I mean, 'Output' is Array of struct!
for example

```
Output(0) :
lDate = 20200801
dMoney = 30000.00

Output(1) :
lDate = 20200901
dMoney = 40000.00

Output(2) :
lDate = 20201001
dMoney = 35000.00

...
```

Comment: Where is the code in C++?

Comment: Also are you sure `#pragma pack(8)` should be working? Since your (VB?) declaration doesn't specify how struct pack. Maybe you could remove that line

Comment: C++ code is  second and fourth grey area. That is #pragma pack(8)~ }stOutput;
#pragma pop and extern "C" long FuncExport __stdcall Calc_Salary(stOutput *Output);

Comment: The other C++ code is just multiply, sum, divide, minus else.. ; very easy operation. So I just skipped it. It just likes Output[1].dMoney = 12*Salary*(1-Tax).. like this

Comment: @LouisGo Also, If I skipped pragma pack then it makes problem worse. Because I found that when I debug with dll source then initial input comes to dll as garbage value.

Comment: Since I don't use VB so I cannot reproduce your problem. But I highly doubt you have incorrect padding settings for the struct. Check your C++ and vb program carefully to see if the padding is correct. If it's not working when you remove `#pragma pack`. It's probably your two program are NOT both 32bit or 64 bits. The better way is to use p/invoke instead of using pack since it will have better interoperability. Post your full struct might help to check that. Also pre set a value for each field might help you to find the problem. So you may see if the value is correct both in C++ and vb.